# San Ysidro Border Parking Options?

Tags: automobiles, mexico, land-borders, san-diego

Just got back from the San Ysidro border area and was dismayed to see that the going rate is now around $25/day for parking. It used to be closer to $5-$7 but I guess there was a re-routing of the I-5 highway that closed one of the bigger lots and now there are just a series of smaller lots that are price gouging? The "posted" rates are $7 but they don't tell you that this is just for 8 hours and 24 hours is $25. I didn't do extensive searching but I saw a few lots with this same prices.

So does anyone have the latest information for cheap(er) parking options down there? Are there options to park somewhere in San Diego and take the trolley down there?

Answer (score 4):

> Are there options to park somewhere in San Diego and take the trolley down there?

The UC San Diego [Blue Line](https://www.sdmts.com/schedules-real-time-maps-and-routes/trolley) runs from America Plaza Station to San Ysidro International Border about every 15 minutes and takes about 45 minutes. Prices [here](https://www.sdmts.com/fares-passes).

On the Green Line free parking is marked, eg at Old Town. From Old Town the journey would be about 20 minutes longer, of which about 1 minute would be on foot.